# What windows messages must I handle when I host a Win32 window inside a WPF control?

Tags: wpf, winapi, hwndhost, wpf-interop

So far, I only know I must listen for WM_CLOSE, which is a request to close, and WM_DESTROY, which is when the window is actually destroyed after closing. I need to handle these because I need to avoid a useless Win32 host view with a closed Win32 window.

Are there any other termination type messages? I wouldn't mind knowing if the module hosting the window is unstable for some reason, which would also force me to close my host view.

Comment: You may be interested in `WM_NCDESTROY`. it is sent *after* all child windows (if there are any) are destroyed, unlike `WM_DESTROY`, which is sent *before* child windows are destroyed.